# Максимальная длина запроса в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Какая может быть максимальная длина запроса в `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обленились, батенька:

[`http://www.google.ru/search?q=Максимальная+длина+запроса+в+MySQL`](http://www.google.ru/search?q=Максимальная+длина+запроса+в+MySQL)